# Xrandr equivalent in Wayland?

Tags: 16.04, xorg, desktop-environments, display-resolution, wayland

I've started testing different DEs for Ubuntu because of the Unity news last week. Some of them use Wayland and I like them, but since sometimes I use xrandr to emulate a higher-than-native resolution with newrez I'm left wondering what the tools would be to achieve this on Wayland.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Thanks, but since then I've just migrated to using xorg on my notebook to supersample higher-than-native resolutions with xrandr, and migrated to windows on the desktop computer since the nvidia driver has a handy GUI to make that as well. I will close this since wayland isn't mandatory for now and xorg just works much better for this purpose.